# Analytical function: sum the cumulative of previous column

Tags: postgresql, running-totals

Using an analytical function, I want that the column 'sum' contains the
cumulative of the previous column.

But my code gets the total sum of all encounters.

Here is both table and data for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(50)
);

CREATE TABLE orders_catalog (
    order_code INT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_desc CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
    cost REAL NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE encounter (
    encounter_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    encounter_type CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_encounter FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_code INT NOT NULL,
    encounter_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    CONSTRAINT FK_orders_catalog FOREIGN KEY (order_code) REFERENCES orders_catalog (order_code),
    CONSTRAINT FK_orders_encounter FOREIGN KEY (encounter_id) REFERENCES encounter(encounter_id)
);
--

INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) VALUES(1, 'Peter');
INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) VALUES(2, 'Charles');
INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) VALUES(3, 'Eva') ;
INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) VALUES(4, 'John');
INSERT INTO users(user_id, name) VALUES(5, 'Helene');

INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10000, 'Painting', 100.34);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10001, 'Painting', 214.11);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10002, 'Painting', 214.11);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10003, 'Spare part', 181.03);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10004, 'Sheet metal', 168.18);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10005, 'Sheet metal', 240.02);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10006, 'Sheet metal', 240.02);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10007, 'Electricity', 146.85);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10008, 'Spare part', 162.13);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10009, 'Electricity', 140.02);
INSERT INTO orders_catalog(order_code, order_desc, cost) VALUES (10010, 'Electricity', 180.02);

INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(100,1,'appointment');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(101,2,'appointment');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(102,3,'appointment');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(103,4,'urgent');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(104,5,'urgent');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(105,1,'appointment');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(106,2,'appointment');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(107,3,'waiting');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(108,4,'urgent');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(109,5,'waiting');
INSERT INTO encounter(encounter_id, user_id, encounter_type) VALUES(110,1,'waiting');

INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1000,10000,100,'2009-06-16 09:12');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1001,10001,101,'2009-06-16 09:12');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1002,10002,102,'2009-06-16 09:12');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1003,10003,103,'2009-12-03 09:50');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1004,10004,104,'2010-02-24 12:21');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1005,10005,105,'2010-03-27 23:54');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1006,10006,106,'2010-03-22 12:43');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1007,10007,107,'2010-02-24 12:21');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1008,10008,108,'2010-03-04 08:55');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1009,10009,109,'2010-03-06 09:25');
INSERT INTO orders(order_id, order_code, encounter_id, created_dt) VALUES (1010,10010,110,'2010-03-22 11:18');
```

And here is the query that I tried:

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY o.created_dt ASC
  ) AS position,
  SUM (c.cost) OVER (
    PARTITION BY o.encounter_id
  ) AS cost,
  SUM (cost) OVER (
    PARTITION BY u.user_id
  ) AS sum
FROM
  users u
INNER JOIN
  encounter e USING (user_id)
INNER JOIN
  orders o USING (encounter_id)
INNER JOIN
  orders_catalog c USING (order_code)
ORDER BY name, position;
```

But the output is not what I expect:

| user_id | name | position | cost | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Charles | 1 | 214.11 | 454.13 |
| 2 | Charles | 2 | 240.02 | 454.13 |
| 3 | Eva | 1 | 214.11 | 360.96002 |
| 3 | Eva | 2 | 146.85 | 360.96002 |
| 5 | Helene | 1 | 168.18 | 308.2 |
| 5 | Helene | 2 | 140.02 | 308.2 |
| 4 | John | 1 | 181.03 | 343.16 |
| 4 | John | 2 | 162.13 | 343.16 |
| 1 | Peter | 1 | 100.34 | 520.38 |
| 1 | Peter | 2 | 180.02 | 520.38 |
| 1 | Peter | 3 | 240.02 | 520.38 |

Since I would want something like:

| user_id | name | position | cost | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | Peter | 1 | 100.34 | 100.34 |
| 1 | Peter | 2 | 180.02 | 280.36 |
| 1 | Peter | 3 | 240.02 | 520.38 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b1d4f189daa67f2c6de45594d50005ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` definition lacks an important component, the key detail that turns a regular window aggregate into a running total, or cumulative aggregate if you will – the `ORDER BY` clause.  In this case, the `ORDER BY` criterion should be the same as the one used in the `position` definition, i.e. `o.created_dt ASC`.

Therefore, your complete query should look like this:

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY o.created_dt ASC
  ) AS position,
  SUM (c.cost) OVER (
    PARTITION BY o.encounter_id
  ) AS cost,
  SUM (cost) OVER (
    PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY o.created_dt ASC
  ) AS sum
FROM
  users u
INNER JOIN
  encounter e USING (user_id)
INNER JOIN
  orders o USING (encounter_id)
INNER JOIN
  orders_catalog c USING (order_code)
ORDER BY name, position;
```

Output:

| user_id | name | position | cost | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Charles | 1 | 214.11 | 214.11 |
| 2 | Charles | 2 | 240.02 | 454.13 |
| 3 | Eva | 1 | 214.11 | 214.11 |
| 3 | Eva | 2 | 146.85 | 360.96 |
| 5 | Helene | 1 | 168.18 | 168.18 |
| 5 | Helene | 2 | 140.02 | 308.2 |
| 4 | John | 1 | 181.03 | 181.03 |
| 4 | John | 2 | 162.13 | 343.16 |
| 1 | Peter | 1 | 100.34 | 100.34 |
| 1 | Peter | 2 | 180.02 | 280.36 |
| 1 | Peter | 3 | 240.02 | 520.38 |

This solution can be tested and played with in a [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cfdc277a39bff635184196aa048823c0&hide=3) at db<>fiddle.

Comment: You should add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` because the default is `RANGE`

Comment: @Charlieface: It probably wouldn't hurt if I did, though I'm not entirely convinced that I should.

Comment: If one user had two orders at the same time then you would get incorrect results, because `created_dt` is not unique. See modified fiddle, `Peter` gets a different result (I have changed the last order) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8c663046311cf133b412fe41da3da280

Comment: @Charlieface: That issue has to do with the ORDER BY not being deterministic enough. My understanding is the OP's ORDER BY shouldn't produce ties *in practice* (two distinct orders involving the same user aren't supposed to have exactly the same timestamp), though it can *in theory*, as you've demonstrated. And this theoretical edge case would be better resolved, if needed, with a better ORDER BY, IMHO. For instance, you could change it to `ORDER BY o.created_dt ASC, o.encounter_id ASC` (in both cases), [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=76ebe900e07de120ecb7530f2786b11d)

Comment: That may be, but the uniqueness issue is not obvious, and it's probably better to be explicit about the calculation. And I don't know about Postgres, but on SQL Server `ROWS` is always more efficient than `RANGE`